# How to create a new user with the role and permission from another user on Linux

Tags: linux

Currently we are developing a .sh file to run a program on Linux. But we've got a problem bellow:
- When running this .sh script with the root permission, we could access to XServer and the program work properly.
- But when running this .sh script with a customized user (the user was defined in this .sh script like this the issue **Unable to connect to X Server** Issue will be occurred

```
grep customizeduser /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    useradd -b /opt/spirent/execute-service customizeduser 
fi
chown -R customizeduser:customizeduser /opt/spirent/customizeduser
```

So my question is, how could we grant permission of this customizeduser from root user?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)?

Comment: @kaylum : yes, how to set full role of sudo for this customizeduser

Answer (score 0):

You edit /etc/sudoers file and give full sudo privileges to the customize user

```
# visudo 
 customusers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or

```
# vim /etc/sudoers
  customusers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakib, I'll follow your instructions